# Running Visual Studio Load Test From Build Definition

Tags: visual-studio, build, load-testing, microsoft-test-manager

I created a build definition that runs automated tests using MTM build environments and test suites.  I recently created a Visual Studio Load Test, which can be added to a test suite just like any test method marked with the [TestMethod] attribute.  However, when I run the build, I get no errors and it appears the aggregate tests don't run.  Is there a way to make this work?

I found this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/testingspot/2013/01/22/how-to-automatically-run-a-load-test-as-part-of-a-build/ which describes a way to do it, but I can't find a build template that matches what he describes, and it appears this only allows you to run a single load test.

Also, when you configure a test controller, there is an option to configure it for load testing, but to do this, you must unregister it from the Team Project Collection.  If this is done, it appears the controller can no longer be used in an environments to run project automated tests.  This defeats the purpose of what I want to do and makes it seem that Load Tests and Team Projects are mutually exclusive.  Is this the case?  If so, this is a big oversight.  Load tests are the kind of thing you would like to run automatically.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are unfortunately right. A test controller used for load testing cannot be used for other automated test execution 'at the same time'. In your scenario I would recommend that you setup a different test controller and agent for load testing and you would be able to queue it as a part of your build to achieve what you are looking for.

There is no special build process template for this case.